# Растянуть содержимое ячейки по вертикали

Tags: opera, html, internet-explorer, css

Как растянуть содержимое ячейки таблицы по вертикали? Предполагается, что содержимое другой ячейки меняется динамически.

Я сделал так:

```
<table>
    <tr height="100%">
        <td>
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>       
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; height: inherit">
            <textarea style="height: inherit"></textarea>               
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Но не работает в IE9 и в Опере. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].style.height=document.getElementById('one').offsetHeight
где #one вставишь <td style="vertical-align: top; height: inherit" id="one">.
```

С похожей проблемой никаким СSS способом я не смог когда-то решить

Answer (score 1):

Для растягивания textarea по высоте на 100% в ИЕ и Опере у родителя должна быть фиксированная высота. Обычно такую задачу решают привлекая javascript и подставляя нужную высоту (высчитывая в зависимости от контента первой ячейки).
Если стоит задача обойтись только CSS решение может быть следующим

```
<table style="position:relative;">
    <tr height="100%">
        <td>
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>          
            <div>Hello</div>       
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; height: inherit; position:absolute;">
            <textarea style="height: 95%;"></textarea>               
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Устанавливаем для всей таблицы position:relative;, для контейнера textarea (в нашем случае это ячейка таблицы - position:absolute. Высоту textarea - уменьшаем со 100% до 95% (вызвано это тем, что таблица вылезет за пределы ячейки благодаря своим границам и отступам. - высоту подбираем максимально подходящую экспериментальным путем).
Есть смысл добавлять эти стили только для ИЕ и Оперы. Плюс может понадобиться более детальное тестирование приближенное к реальному проекту.